# bash check if input doesn't contain a file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I want to write a script that displays an error message when the user input contains an argument that isn't a file.

for example:

```
./script.sh test.pdf test1.pdf test2.pdf
```

should work fine.

but:

```
./script.sh test.pdf test1.pdf notAfile
```

should display an error message.

The script should be tolerant for a [-b int] option you can put before the files.

For example

```
./script.sh -b 5 test.pdf test1.pdf test2.pdf
```

Should run fine aswell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-b` parameter makes it a bit tricky. Here's a portable way to do it:

```
b_seen=
b=
for arg; do
    if test "$b_seen"; then
        b="$arg"
        b_seen=
    elif test "$arg" = -b; then
        b_seen=yes
    elif test ! -f "$arg"; then
        echo error: not a file: $arg
    fi
done
```

It has a limitation: if there are multiple -b, the last will overwrite previous

Answer (score 2):

For command line argument parsing, check [getopt](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt). Example:

```
args=($(getopt -u '-o b:' -- $@))
files=false
for i in "${args[@]}"; do
        $files && [ ! -f "$i" ] && echo "File not found: $i"
        if [ "$i" == '--' ]; then files=true; fi
done
```

Comment: Sorry i missed a part, there is an option wherein you can pass a -b option to the script. of course I don't want it to check if the -b option is a file. `./script.sh -b 5 test.pdf test1.pdf test2.pdf` should run aswell

Comment: is there maybe some kind of `for i in "$3" to "$@" do ... done`

Comment: See edit. In order to support more command line options you need to add them to `getopt`.  `-o b:` registers an option `-b` which requires an argument for example. See manpage for more.

Comment: I did read (and upvote) your edit. I am reading in to it right now. Thank you for your help!